# Continuous rotate image onclick of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox

To display Image I used colorbox..In that I have add rotate-left and rotate-right to rotate the image..
The code is:

```
var rotate_right = document.getElementById('cboxRight');
$(rotate_right).on('click', function () {
    var cboxphoto = document.getElementsByClassName('cboxPhoto')[0].style;
    cboxphoto.setAttribute('-ms-transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
});

var rotate_left = document.getElementById('cboxLeft');
$(rotate_left).on('click', function () {
    var cboxphoto = document.getElementsByClassName('cboxPhoto')[0].style;
    cboxphoto.setAttribute('-ms-transform', 'rotate(270deg)');
});
```

It rotate 90deg if I click again on rightrotate button then it wont work..I want to rotate it again when click on button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're only ever rotating to 90 or 270 degrees. When you click again, it doesn't move as it is already rotated to that angle.

Keep track of the current rotation instead and set the attribute to that value plus or minus 90deg - you can probably clean up the code a bit as well, but something like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w6ho689e/

```
    var degrees = 0;
$("#cboxRight").on('click', function () {
    var $cboxphoto = $('.cboxPhoto');
    degrees += 90;
    $cboxphoto.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
    $cboxphoto.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
    $cboxphoto.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
});

$("#cboxLeft").on('click', function () {
    var $cboxphoto = $('.cboxPhoto');
    degrees -= 90;
    $cboxphoto.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
    $cboxphoto.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
    $cboxphoto.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
});
```

Comment: Pleasure! Remember to click the accept button to help future rotators ;)

Comment: can I directly set `cboxphoto.setAttribute('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');` bcz it works only in IE not in chrome,FF and safari @EvanKnowles

Comment: @Deb The `-ms` in your transform indicates that it's only for IE. There are Chrome and Firefox versions, you just need to set some additional properties: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp I'll update the example.

Comment: I have set same thing but it shows error `cboxphoto.setAttribute is not a function`

Comment: That's most likely how the different browsers set attributes - I see you're using jQuery, so I'll update it to use jQuery instead.

Comment: `Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'` error @EvanKnowles

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @EvanKnowles 2.1.1jquery

Comment: Updated to fix this, and included an example JSFiddle for you.

Comment: thnx alot for ur time :)